# Why 'mouseover' does not work to simulate hover in some cases?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to simulate a mouse hover event, but while on certain elements it works as expected, on one in particular it doesn't.

This is what's not working:

```
function simulateMouseover(target) {
  var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  }); 
  var canceled = !target.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert("not canceled");
  }
}
```

Then call it on a stored global element:

```
simulateMouseover(temp1);
```

The example needs a use case, so here's a random FB gaming live, where you can only get the publish time of a stream programatically if you hover over the date of it.

https://www.facebook.com/RealScottyBlades/videos/179401634042952

While calling the function on the avatar of a person that commented works (shows the pop-up), for the date at the top it does not. Any suggestion why this is the case, or how could I fix it in pure JS?